# Find the distance from point of observation when angles of depression are unknown

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

If the two angles of depression are the same how do I determine the distance from the point of observation is?

[image: Diagram of problem]

Answer (score 1):

Let our triangle be $\Delta ABC$,  $\measuredangle C=90^{\circ}$, $AD$ be bisector of the triangle,

where $\measuredangle CAD=\measuredangle BAD=\theta$ and $AC=x$.

Thus, by the Pythagoras theorem $$AB=\sqrt{x^2+3.6^2}$$ and since
$$\frac{AC}{AB}=\frac{CD}{BD},$$ we obtain:
$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+3.6^2}}=\frac{1.6}{2}$$ or
$$x^2=0.64(x^2+3.6^2)$$ or
$$0.36x^2=0.64\cdot3.6^2$$ or
$$0.6x=0.8\cdot3.6$$ or
$$x=4.8.$$

I used the following theorem.

> Let $AD$ be bisector of $\Delta ABC$.
>
> Hence, $$\frac{AC}{AB}=\frac{CD}{BD}$$

Comment: Can you break it down a little more to show how you firstly got the above equation and how to eventually get to the answer please? so I fully understanding the workings.

Comment: @Maths Geek I added something. See now.

Comment: Thanks that's great.

Comment: can you show how you got from the obtained equation to how you get the answer x = 4.8? thanks

Answer (score 0):

use that $$\tan(2\theta)=\frac{3.6}{m}$$ and $$\tan(2\theta)=\frac{2\tan(\theta)}{1-\tan^2(\theta)}$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

$\require{cancel}$

From $\triangle ABC$, $x=(u+v)\cot2\theta$,
similarly, from $\triangle ADC$, $x=u\cot\theta$,
hence,
\begin{align} 
(u+v)\cot2\theta&=u\cot\theta
,\\
\cot2\theta\tan\theta
&=\frac{u}{u+v}
,\\
\frac{\cos2\theta}{\sin2\theta}\cdot\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}
&=\frac{u}{u+v}
,\\
\frac{\cos2\theta}{2\,\cancel{\sin\theta}\cdot\cos\theta}
\cdot\frac{\cancel{\sin\theta}}
{\cos\theta}
&=\frac{u}{u+v}
,\\
\frac{2\cos^2\theta-1}{2\,\cos^2\theta}
&=\frac{u}{u+v}
,\\
1-\frac{u}{u+v}
&=
\frac{1}{2\,\cos^2\theta}
,\\
\frac{v}{u+v}
&=
\frac{1}{2\,\cos^2\theta}
,\\
2\,\cos^2\theta&=\frac{u+v}{v}
,\\
\cos\theta&=\pm\sqrt{\frac{u+v}{2\,v}}
.
\end{align}
Note that $\theta<90^\circ$, hence $\cos\theta>0$,
we need only positive value of the square root:

\begin{align} 
\cos\theta&=\sqrt{\frac{u+v}{2\,v}}
,\\
\cot\theta&=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{u+v}{2\,v}}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{u+v}{2\,v}}}
=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{u+v}{2\,v}}}{\sqrt{\frac{v-u}{2\,v}}}
\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{u+v}{v-u}}
,\\
x&=u\,\sqrt{\frac{u+v}{v-u}}
.
\end{align}

For $u=1.6,v=2$ we have
\begin{align} 
x&=1.6\,\sqrt{\frac{3.6}{0.4}}
=1.6\,\sqrt{9}
=4.8\,
.
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
\end{align}